# Improving the parsing speed

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to extract the headers from three fasta files and compare their headers. However, it only works with smaller files. When the files are in couple GB in size, the python script kills itself.

My code is :

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def get_header(filename):
    parts = SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta')
    headers = map(lambda x: x.id, parts)
    return set(headers)

bact1 = get_header('file1.fasta')
bact2 = get_header('file2.fasta')
bact3 = get_header('file3.fasta')


print 'Only in bact1:', len(bact1 - bact2 - bact3)
print 'Only in bact2:', len(bact2 - bact1 - bact3)
print 'Only in bact3:', len(bact3 - bact1 - bact2)
```

I would appreciate if you can show an insight.

Comment: If you're only doing things in-memory, you can't really expect much more improvement from what you've shown here. To work with larger files, you have to treat your hard disk as memory.

Comment: Is the problem that this is too slow or that your python instance runs out of memory?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq it is very slow with smaller files too, but at least it works. If it runs with larger files, it runs for couple hours and then kills itself. The problem is that I have memory, around 2 TB.

Comment: Is it possible to parse this data in chunks? And regularly write out any work you've done to disk so that this work isn't completely lost a couple hours in. For example, write the `id`'s to disk, then hash, then sort, then throw those hashes into a set, subtract, and map the remaining hashes back to their original values.